# mysql - isolation level, wait for transaction to commit during the records search

Tags: mysql

I have 5 virtual FreeBsd servers. Each of them running a java application, which uses spring jdbc pool of connections to a mysql server.

Each of them starts 1000 transactions in 1000 threads.

The logic of each transaction is:

```
check is '123' exists in db
if it does, insert it with status 'OK'
else insert it with status 'DUP'
```

I run all transactions with '123', so only the 'first' one should insert with 'OK', all others should insert with 'DUP'

But, in reality, it starts to save 'DUP' only from Nth transaction, not from the second, because while the very first transaction is still committing '123', N transactions has already checked '123' in DB and didn't find it, because the very first transaction is still  working. And when the very first one completed, all others starts to save 'DUP'. This is bad behavior.

So the question is: is there any ability to check that there is a transaction which trying to save '123', and if it is, hold all other transactions which trying to find '123' in DB. Or is there any better solution? I tried all isolation levels, but only serializable works, and I know why, but it dramatically impacts the performance.

Comment: Not readable, refactor your text.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? Where/When do you start your transaction?